# How to fix the position of arc on a circular border after animation in css

Tags: html, css

I am creating a css design where i need to animate the arc on a circular border i   have found a code online and with few changes it allows me to rotate the border but however after rotation it come backs to its initial position i want to keep it at the exact same position where it stooped after animation is completed. Here  is the code

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.circle .border {

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width:10px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-top-color:orange;
  border-left-color:transparent;
  border-bottom-color:transparent;
  border-right-color:transparent;
  -webkit-animation-name: Rotate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.play {
  padding: 20px 30px;
  font-size: 56px;
}
.stop {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
@-webkit-keyframes Rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div class="play"><i class="fa fa-play"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<p>
  PS: The icon loading is a bit slow. Wait until it shows up.
</p>

<div class="circle">
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div class="stop">Stop me please</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

property

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.circle .border {

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width:10px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-top-color:orange;border-left-color:transparent;border-bottom-color:transparent;border-right-color:transparent;
  -webkit-animation-name: Rotate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.play {
  padding: 20px 30px;
  font-size: 56px;
}
.stop {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
@-webkit-keyframes Rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div class="play"><i class="fa fa-play"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<p>
  PS: The icon loading is a bit slow. Wait until it shows up.
</p>

<div class="circle">
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div class="stop">Stop me please</div>
</div>
```